# Duplicate key error INSERTing a unique value

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-rds

I've just moved a self-hosted PostgreSQL database onto AWS RDS and now have a strange duplicate key problem.

I have a table `patient` which contains an `email` column which must be unique, and this is enforced by a unique index:

```
Indexes:
    "patient_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_patient_email" UNIQUE, btree (email)
    ...
```

I am getting an error on `INSERT` that reports a key violation

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_patient_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(***) already exists.
```

yet when I `SELECT` filtering with the same email, there are no records.

I've tried reindexing the column, the table and the whole database, but still get the same problem. Reindexing was very quick, but I only have 5000 records.

```
reindex (verbose) table patient;
INFO:  index "patient_pkey" was reindexed
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.02 s
INFO:  index "ix_patient_email" was reindexed
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.01 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.03 s
```

Any suggestions on how to further investigate where the problem is, or how to fix this?

Comment: 1) What happens if you drop the index and try the insert? 2) After 1) create the index again and try the insert and see what happens? 3) What is the encoding/character set for the database and the client? 4) Postgres version? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: To be clear, dropping and the recreating the index is what worked?

Comment: Its likely your index is corrupted, rebuild is the best solution here.